# Replicate header in the footer without regeneration

Tags: fancyhdr, qrcode

I am using the `qrcode` package to put qr codes in the right header of my document using `fancyhdr`. Each page has a different qr code in its header.

I now need the same qrcode image to appear in the footer so that each oage has two identical qr codes top and bottom. At present I am just using the same `\qrcode` command for the footer but this means compiling takes longer as it does the work twice.

Is there any way to copy the header content to the footer, even if it is a qr code image?

Comment: Store the qr code image in box? A working example would be nice!

Comment: In fact, according to the document, an existing `qr` code definition is stored already to the `.aux` file and reused and not recalculated.

Comment: After running Hupfer's answer I wound up with 36 copies of the \qr@savematrix definition in the aux file.  What's up with that?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: That's true, but it's faster than to store `\qrcode{http://foo}` into a macro  (at least for my example) with `\blindtext[100]`

Answer (score 2):

This compiles quite quickly, using a savebox to store the code. (actually, it's redone and reread from `.aux` - file apparently)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\newsavebox{\myqrbox}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\myqrbox}{\qrcode{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270765/replicate-header-in-the-footer-without-regeneration}}
\chead{\usebox{\myqrbox}}
\cfoot{\usebox{\myqrbox}}

\blindtext[100]

\end{document}
```

[image]